# AlloyUI : Customize pagination component

Tags: pagination, yui, liferay-6, alloy-ui

Im working with an Alloy UI pagination component in Liferay 6.2 and i was trying to customize the prev and nextc controls, i have something like this :

```
<div id="myDataTable"></div>    
<div id="pagination" class="aui-pagination aui-pagination-centered">
    <ul class="aui-pagination-content">
      <li><a href="#">Prev</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Where myDataTable is ...a DataTable component

and then the YUI code:

```
new Y.Pagination({
        contentBox: '#pagination .aui-pagination-content',
        circular:false,
        page: 1,
        strings: {
            prev:'&laquo;',
            next: '&raquo;',
        },
        on: {
          changeRequest: function(event) {
            if (event.state.page === 1) {
              dataTable.set('data', data1);
            } else if (event.state.page === 2) {
              dataTable.set('data', data2);
            } else if (event.state.page === 3) {
              dataTable.set('data', data3);
            }
          }
        },
        total:3
      }).render();
```

What i want to do is to hide all the pages in the pagination and just have the prev and next controls with a background image, i have noticed that you can change the controls by changing the strings on the YUI code but it only allows ASCII characters and i need to include images or a way to insert css code there. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can do this using CSS. The left navigation button will be first child and the right button will be the last child of pagination-content class. After calling the render method you can set the innerHTML of the navigation buttons through JS

```
Y.one('.pagination-content .pagination-control:first-child').setHTML('<div>Content of left navigation button</div>');
Y.one('.pagination-content .pagination-control:last-child).setHTML('<div>Content of right navigation button</div>');
```

Comment: Hey @Diptendu it worked! thanks a lot. Now im trying to figure out the way to hide the pagination pages (1,2...). I was trying to approach the same method that you used here wrapping the UL with a DIV and then hiding the DIV, the problem is that i can't find a way to target just the <li> elements that are pages and not the control images (i guess trying to use an if loop?). Any ideas will be really appreciated im new to YUI so still trying to figure out a lot of things.

Comment: Problem solved with :
Y.all('.pagination-content li:nth-of-type(n+2):nth-last-of-type(n+2)').addClass('desaparece');
and then add display none to those elements by:
ocultar = Y.all('.desaparece');ocultar.setStyle('display','none');

Comment: Great. I was about to suggest you Y.one('.pagination-content').all('li:not(".pagination-control")').setStyle('display', 'none');

Comment: @Diptendy that's way better than my solution tho, thanks ! Is there any tutorial or web where i can read about YUI3 ? i have found a rosetta stone doc but not for things like iterations (if,for,etc) or things like you have done with the li:not.

Comment: But :not is a css3 selector and hence won't work in older browsers.  You can learn about YUI here http:// yuilibrary.com

Comment: Actually now that i have tested is not working for me for some reason.

Comment: If you are planning to use Yui for some new project I would advise you to pick some other library since it is not supported anymore.

Comment: Im using Liferay 6.2 + Alloy UI that's why im using YUI3 to customize some of the AUI components.

Comment: "Actually now that i have tested is not working for me for some reason." - oh . If you could provide some fiddle link then I can take a look. Otherwise your implementation is also fine, its a few lines more but will work in all browsers.

Comment: I will use my implementation just for the sake of crossbrowsing thanks a lot @Diptendu. BTW i already knew that site but just wondering if the implementation of things like conditionals and for loops in YUI3 are build the same way as in javascript, and i'm not able to find that on that site.

Comment: Things like conditionals, loops exception handling are exactly as per definition of ECMA specification. These are basic programming constructs and won't vary in any library. The purpose of these libraries is to enhnace the functionalists (like providing more features on Array object) and to provide methods that are browser agnostic e.g. there is a 'on' method in YUI that wraps addEventListener in FF and attachEvent in IE so that you don't need to change your based on browser.